# ERROR MESSAGE: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in StudentsController#edit Couldn't find Student without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Not able to edit the student deatils. Can someone help me with this problem. Its my first time working on ruby on rails.
This is my edit.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @student do |f| %>
  <%= f.label 'Firstname' %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :firstname %><br>

  <%= f.label 'Lastname' %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :lastname %><br>

  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

This is my StudentsController.rb file:

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController
def index
  @students = Student.all
end 

def create
  @student = Student.new(student_params)

  if @student.save
    redirect_to new_student_path
  end
end

def edit
  @student = Student.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @student = Student.find(params[:id])
  @student.update(firstname: params[:student][:firstname], lastname: params[:student][:lastname])
  redirect_to students_path(@student)
end 


  private
 
  def student_params
    params.require(:student).permit(:firstname, :lastname)
  end

end
```

This is my index.html.erb page: I have provided links to go to add name page and edit page.

```
    <h1>Welcome to my first rails project</h1>
<a href="<%=  new_student_url %>">Click To Add a Name</a>
<br>
<br>
<div class="container">
<b>Displaying names:</b><br><br>


<% if !@students.blank? %>
    <% for item in @students %>

        <%= item.firstname %> <%= item.lastname %><br><br>
    <% end %>
<a href="<%=  students_edit_url %>">Edit</a>
<% else %>
<% end %>  
</div>
```

routes.rb page:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :students, only: [:index, :new, :create, :update]


  get 'students/edit'
  root 'students#index'
end
```

routes command for student

```
 $ rails routes|grep student
 students GET    /students(.:format)                                                                students#index
POST   /students(.:format)
                                                                  students#creat
e
                             new_student GET    /students/new(.:format)
                                                                  students#new
                                 student PATCH  /students/:id(.:format)
                                                                  students#updat
e
                                         PUT    /students/:id(.:format)
                                                                  students#updat
e
                           students_edit GET    /students/edit(.:format)
                                                                  students#edit
                                    root GET    /
                                                                  students#index
```

Comment: Add your routes file as well, or at least the relevant parts from it. Also, how do you get to your edit page, I currently see no buttons/links for that in the index page.

Comment: Please post how you get to the edit page (link/button).

Comment: Can you display the result of the command `rails routes|grep student`?

Comment: Added everything you guys asked for